# Get long locale date format without momentjs

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, date-fns

I have been migrating from moment.js to date-fns and was stuck at a point where couldn't find an alternative for

```
moment.localeData().longDateFormat("LL");
```

For more information :

```
localeData = moment.localeData()
localeData.longDateFormat()
```

returns

```
{
  LT : 'HH:mm',
  LTS : 'HH:mm:ss',
  L : 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  LL : 'D MMMM YYYY',
  LLL : 'D MMMM YYYY HH:mm',
  LLLL : 'dddd, D MMMM YYYY HH:mm'
}
```

In general , is there any alternative for this function in [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) or vanilla js ?

Answer (score 2):

After digging for a while , The [PPP](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/format) format within date-fns , can be used .
Other solution for it can be to use [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) with the suitable parameters as mentioned in the docs .